# Average test score from result array with varying group sizes

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, hashmap

I am working on a problem where I have to calculate the average from a bunch of test results with the following criteria.
-his program was tested on several test case and each test case has the following results.."OK", "Wrong answer", "TimeOut", "Runtime error"
-test cases were organized into groups numbered by consecutive natural numbers
-his program scored points for a group only when the result of every test case in the group was "OK"
for instance if test case names are test1, test2a, test2b, test2c, test3, test4. In this case test2a, test2b, test2c all form one group and must all score OK to receive a collective point.

Write a function

```
class Solution{
public int solution (String[] test, String[] result){}
}
//example:
test[0] = "test1a",  result[0] = "Wrong answer"
test[1] = "test2",  result[1] = "OK"
test[2] = "test1b",  result[2] = "Runtime error"
test[3] = "test1c",  result[0] = "OK"
test[4] = "test3",  result[4] = "Time limit exceeded" 
//result above is 33.
```

Assume integer is within range 1-300
-arrays test and result have the same length
-every test case appears just once
-test case are ordered by consecutive natural integers from 1.
-test cases in groups containing at least two tests are differentiated by a lowercase suffix in alphabetical order from a. 
-each string in results contains one of "OK", "Wrong answer", "TimeOut", "Runtime error"

Right now I wrote code to strip the test String array and get the integers for each test group. Then I created an Integer, Integer HashMap where I check the integers I gathered after using regex and check to ensure all test cases in a group are "OK" before assigning a 100 to them

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
public static int solution(String[] test, String[] result)
{
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> scoreMap =  new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int[] stripped = new int[test.length];

    //stripped the String of numbers..
    for(int i = 0; i < test.length;i++)
    {
       stripped[i] = Integer.parseInt(test[i].replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
    }

    //working with just the numbers from the test groups array
    for(int i = 0; i < stripped.length; i++)
    {
        if(scoreMap.containsKey(stripped[i]))
        {
            if(result[i].equals("OK"))
                scoreMap.put(stripped[i], 100);

            else
                scoreMap.put(stripped[i], 0);
        }

        else
        {
            if(result[i].equals("OK"))
                scoreMap.put(stripped[i], 100);

            else
                scoreMap.put(stripped[i], 0);
        }

    }

    int correctAnswers = 0;
    for(int val: scoreMap.values())
    {
        if(val == 100)
            correctAnswers++;
    }

    double avg =  correctAnswers/scoreMap.size() * 100;

    return (int)Math.floor(avg); 

    //return Math.floor(correctAnswers/scoreMap.size() * 100);

}


public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // your code goes here
    String[] test1 = {"test1", "test2a", "test2b", "test4", "test2c", "test3", "test5", "test6", "test7"};
    String[] results1 = {"OK", "OK", "Wrong answer", "OK", "Wrong answer", "Wrong answer", "OK", "TimeOut","Runtime error"}; 
    int average1 =  solution(test1, results1);

    String[] test2 = {"stackoverflow1", "stackoverflow2a", "stackoverflow2b", "stackoverflow4", "stackoverflow2c", "stackoverflow3", "stackoverflow5", "stackoverflow6", "stackoverflow7"};
    String[] results2 = {"Runtime error", "OK", "Wrong answer", "OK", "TimeOut", "Wrong answer", "OK", "Timeout","TimeOut"};

    int average2 =  solution(test2, results2);

    String[] test3 = {"test1", "test2a", "test2b", "test4", "test2c", "test3", "test5", "test6", "test7"};
    String[] results3 = {"OK", "OK", "TimeOut", "OK", "TimeOut", "OK", "TimeOut", "Runtime error","OK"}; 
    int average3 =  solution(test3, results3);

    System.out.println("Avg1 = " + average1);
    System.out.println("Avg2 = " + average2);
    System.out.println("Avg3 = " + average3);

}
```

}

Comment: From your spec, _FAIL_ should be named  _Wrong answer_ in your array initializers. This is not the solution to your problem, but a problem that might occur when not using enums.

Comment: Not entirely relevant to the core issue at hand but ok,

Comment: Edited the code to illustrate that the tests can be named differently... could be test1, test2a, test2b or stacktest1, stacktest2 so regex string has to be flexible.

Answer (score 2):

If i have understood you correctly, a test case can either consist of a single test or multiple tests, formly speaking of a test suite.

Lets introduce the following two classes:

```
private static class TestSuiteResult {
    private String name;
    private List<TestResult> results = new ArrayList<>();

    public TestSuiteResult(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<TestResult> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
}

private static class TestResult {
    private String name;
    private String result;

    public TestResult(String name, String result) {
        this.name = name;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Next, lets try to parse the input `String[] tests` and `String[] results` to above classes.
The regular expression `test(\d*)([a-z])?` matches any input that start with `test`, followed by any number of digits, optionally followed by a character from a-z. The capturing groups are used to extract the needed pieces.

```
String regex = "(\\w*?)(\\d*)([a-z])?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

Map<String, TestResult> testResults = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, TestSuiteResult> testSuiteResults = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {

    String test = tests[i];
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

    // check for illegal test name
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        continue;
    }

    String name = matcher.group(1);
    String digitPart = matcher.group(2);
    String character = matcher.group(3);

    if (character != null) {
        // multi test
        String suiteName = name + digitPart;
        TestSuiteResult suite = testSuiteResults.get(digitPart);
        TestSuiteResult suite = testSuiteResults.get(suiteName);
        if (suite == null) {
            suite = new TestSuiteResult(suiteName);
            testSuiteResults.put(suite.getName(), suite);
        }
        String result = results[i];
        TestResult multi = new TestResult(character, result);
        suite.getResults().add(multi);
    } else {
        // single test
        String result = results[i];
        TestResult single = new TestResult(test, result);
        testResults.put(single.getName(), single);
    }
}
```

Nextup, we can calculate the total amount of tests and from the total amount of valid tests. I have considered a test suite as a single test here, which is only valid if all of its contained tests are valid.

```
int totalAmountOfTests = testResults.size() + testSuiteResults.size();

int validTests = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, TestResult> entry : testResults.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().getResult().equals("OK")) {
        validTests++;
    }
}
for (Map.Entry<String, TestSuiteResult> entry : testSuiteResults.entrySet()) {
    List<TestResult> suiteResults = entry.getValue().getResults();
    boolean valid = true;
    for (TestResult suiteResult : suiteResults) {
        if (!suiteResult.getResult().equals("OK")) {
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    if (valid) {
        validTests++;
    }
}
```

Now, finally we can calculate the average amount of tests that passed. When casting `average` to an `int` we round to the lower digit.

```
double average = (double) totalAmountOfTests / validTests;
int averageRounded = (int) average;
```

The complete, working example is available [here](https://gist.github.com/glains/ae507332b0296c59ca8c74c858fb5386).

Comment: Edited the code to illustrate that the tests can be named differently... could be test1, test2a, test2b or stacktest1, stacktest2 so regex string has to be flexible.                                              Also explain the //multi test portion. Why did you select the suite to be the value. I understand the String digit part being the key though.

Comment: Maybe including a visual of what an iteration of the map looks like being populated based on the test cases I gave in the main method would help

Comment: You can take a `List` as well, but a `Map` is way faster since you don´t need to iterate over all entries each time you check if one already exists.

Comment: I have change the answer based on your requirements. Instead of taking the time for a visual, i recommend you have a look with your local debugger.

Answer (score 0):

So, the important part is task ID. Let's group answers by task id:
**1=[Wrong answer, Runtime error, OK], 2=[OK], 3=[Time limit exceeded]**

Next we can convert answers to boolean if it's OK or not:
**1=[false, false, true], 2=[true], 3=[false]**

Then reduce them:
**1=false, 2=true, 3=false**

And calculate the final result:
**1 * 100 / 3**

Kotlin code:

```
fun solution(T: Array<String>, R: Array<String>): Int {
    return T.asSequence()
        .map { Regex("\\w+(\\d+)").find(it) }
        .filterNotNull()
        .map { it.destructured.component1().toInt() }
        .zip(R.asSequence().map { it == "OK" })
        .groupingBy { it.first }
        .fold(true) { acc, el -> acc && el.second }
        .let { map -> map.values.count { it } * 100 / map.size }
}
```